# In Leaflet, how to change "crs" and other "Map options"?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

For example, I create  a map like this:

```
    map = L.map('map',
        {maxZoom: 17,
        attributionControl: false,
        zoomControl: false}
    )
```

Later, I want to change the "crs" and add a key to the `map` object.

I expect there might be a method called `setOption`, like this:

```
map.setOption({crs:L.CRS.BEPSG3857, customOption: true})
```

But unfortunately there is no such `setOption` method..Does anyone have ideas about how to change the `Map option` for a leaflet map object?

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2553 , Dynamically changing projection after map is initialized is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

Check this example on how to change crs on the fly: http://jsfiddle.net/alekzonder/qxdxqsm3/

```
var center = map.getCenter();

if (...) {
   map.options.crs = L.CRS.EPSG3395;
} else {
   map.options.crs = L.CRS.EPSG3857;
}

map.setView(center);

map._resetView(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom());
```

Comment: Excelent example, but it doesn't work with Leaflet v1.2.0. I broke my mind when trying to modify it. Can you help to get it work with version 1.2.0?

Comment: Looks to be working, updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sboulema/nan7Lhxb/

What is not working for you ?!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I needed to dynamically set the scrollWheelZoom option.

I'm using L.version 1.3.1

If scrollWheelZoom option is true on map init, it will enable the corresponding [Handler](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#handler).
Therefore we need to enable/disable the handler manually to apply the changes to the map.

[List of handlers/map-properties](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-property): boxZoom, doubleClickZoom, dragging, keyboard, scrollWheelZoom, tap, touchZoom

[My solution](https://github.com/jhotadhari/geo-masala/blob/b8b3ce0186d706672f7cf8d23cc15e966710e191/src/commonJS/geom_block_map_editor/components/Map.jsx) looks somehow like this:

```
class MyMap {

    // constructor(props) {
    //  ...
    // }

    // getMapElement(){
    //  ...
    // }

    // getBaseLayer(){
    //  ...
    // }

    initMap( mapOptions ){
        if ( ! this.map  ) {
            this.map = L.map( this.getMapElement(), mapOptions );
            this.getBaseLayer().addTo( this.map );
        }
    }

    setMapOptions( newMapOptions ){
        // loop newMapOptions object
        for ( let newMapOptionKey in newMapOptions ) {
            if( newMapOptions.hasOwnProperty(newMapOptionKey)) {
                this.setMapOption( newMapOptionKey, newMapOptions[newMapOptionKey] );
            }
        }
    }

    setMapOption( newMapOptionKey, newMapOptionVal ){
        // set map option
        L.Util.setOptions( this.map, {[newMapOptionKey]: newMapOptionVal});
        // apply option to handler
        if ( this.map[newMapOptionKey] instanceof L.Handler ) {
            if ( newMapOptionVal ) {
                this.map[newMapOptionKey].enable();
            } else {
                this.map[newMapOptionKey].disable();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This works for the scrollWheelZoom option. Think it should work for all options that enable/disable handlers. So it might work for your customOption but it won't work for the crs option.

Comment: **Much** easier way: use `map.scrollWheelZoom.enable()` and `map.scrollWheelZoom.disable()`